# Appending JavaScript file reference after the last hard coded JavaScript file reference in the HEAD

Tags: javascript, dom, traversal, appendchild

Apologies if the following sounds a little strange.  Am working in a legacy framework that allows no access to core templates so cannot alter the loading order of files.

What i am trying to do is load a JS file in the HEAD of the document after the final SCRIPt in said document HEAD.

I currently am using the following with no success:

```
var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0]; 

var headScripts = head.getElementsByTagName("script");

var headScriptsLength = headScripts.length - 1;

var headScripts = headScripts[headScriptsLength];

var newScript = document.createElement('script');
newScript.type = 'text/javascript';
newScript.src = '/Global/ICIS/Scripts/global.js';
headScripts.appendChild(newScript);
```

It adds the reference to global.js directly after the block that creates it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You better off appending your script simply to the head, and so it will become your last script.

```
var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0]; 
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = '/Global/ICIS/Scripts/global.js';
head.appendChild(script);
```

Comment: For some reason that produces the following result:    <script type="text/javascript">
var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0]; 
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = '/Global/ICIS/Scripts/global.js';
head.appendChild(script);
</script><script src="/Global/ICIS/Scripts/global.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
So it does not append before the </head> but straight after the script block.

Comment: It does work, because `appendChild` by definition appends the new element to the end. Check this example page: http://jsbin.com/usare4/3/ - it adds jQuery to the head, and has a placeholder `<script>` tag so that you can see, the new script is placed at the end of `<head>`